# How to obtain pseudo-class styles via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm writing a script that has access to a page's DOM, and I want to know what color would a particular link be if it had been visited. I'm aware that I cannot know whether the link has actually been visited, I don't care about that. I just want to know the color set for `a:visited`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the `:visited` style with `window.getComputedStyle` according to the following [MDN blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/) because of privacy rules. So you can't programmatically tell if a user visited a link or not by checking the color.

But you can do it by walking through the stylesheets and search for a specific selector. Then if the selector is a match return the `style.color` property of that set style rule. This will not get the computed value but the value as set in the stylesheet.

```js
const getStyleRuleColor = selector => {
  for (const { rules } of document.styleSheets) {
    for (const { style, selectorText } of rules) {
      if (selectorText === selector) {
        return style.color;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}

const selectorElement = 'a:visited';
const selectorId = '#someid:visited';

const elementVisitedColor = getStyleRuleColor(selectorElement);
const idVisitedColor = getStyleRuleColor(selectorId);

console.log(`${selectorElement} :`, elementVisitedColor);
console.log(`${selectorId} :`, idVisitedColor);
```

```css
a {
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  color: red;
}

#someid:visited {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a id="someid" href="http://someurl.com">I have a color</a>
```

Comment: What if, for example, the rule in the stylesheet is introduced as `#someid:visited { color: green; }` but I use `getStyleRuleColor('a:visited');`? Would that still work?

Comment: No, it won't. It literally reads the stylesheet and the rules as that are declared in the sheet. So if `a:visited` is nowhere in the sheet, then there won't be a hit. Then use `#someid:visited` as the selector to find the `:visited` style.